# Why do SSMS and SSIS produce two different "null date" values?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssis

For years, I have used SSIS (SQL Server Integration Services) to import flatfile data into SQL Server tables. In the event that time-only string fields are cast to datetime fields, I typically see a conversion like this:

```
"13:45" to "1899-12-30 13:45:00.000"
```

Just by chance I noticed that if I do this in a T-SQL query using SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio), this happens:

```
select cast('13:45' as datetime)` produces "1900-01-01 13:45:00.000"
```

I am curious why two different date values appear. If it's all SQL Server, shouldn't the same "null date value" be the same?

Answer (score 0):

You're comparing apples to oranges.  In one, you're probably using OleDb to connect to a datasource, in the other your running a native query.

In the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/native-client-ole-db-date-time/conversions-ole-db) for OleDb you'll see that depending on the settings it will either convert a time to a DateTime with the current date or a date of 1899-12-30.

The SQL Server [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime-transact-sql) explains how it simply puts '1900-01-01' in front when converting from time data.